# Is there better way to filter the Future

Tags: scala, playframework

So I want to write simple login logic in play-framework. Password checking looks like this

```
...
.filter(user => BCrypt.checkpw(req.password, user.password))
...
```

It's working no problem. But when the password is incorrect, I get the exception:

```
Future.filter predicate is not satisfied
```

However, I want to have my own exception to be thrown, so I did like this:

```
...
 .map(user =>
        if (!BCrypt.checkpw(req.password, user.password)) {
          throw WrongCredentials()}
        else user)
...
```

Which works, but I have been wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: you can use recover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like(from the official doc):

```
val purchase: Future[Int] = rateQuote map {
  quote => connection.buy(amount, quote)
} recover {
  case QuoteChangedException() => 0
}
```